# asp.net access an element in session array vb

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, session

I have an VB array of 10 items sImgdesc(0) thru sImgdesc(9) that I need to store and retrieve on different pages. I would like to save the array to a session variable but I don't know how to do it. I've read the many examples here but none of them are clear on how to refer to an individual session array element say sImgdesc(4) or sImgdesc(5) etc.

I would like an example of how to do this using VB. I've looked at this example

```
Dim myDoubleArray() As Double = New Double() {1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4}
Session("DoubleList") = myDoubleArray
Dim sessionDoubles() As Double = CType(Session("DoubleList"),Double())
```

but, I am confused on how to get a particular item. How would I get/reference say item 2 which (1.3) in the above example?

Any help in getting me to understand this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `sessionDoubles(2)` not giving you the value 1.3 in your example?

Comment: Whats the behavior you're seeing?  this example looks fine.

Comment: yes, it does. So if I want to change that to say 4.5 do I say sessionDoubles(2) = 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

here you have an example

```
Public Shared Function update_notification() As String
    For Each element In HttpContext.Current.Session("idTicket")
        Dim closed As DataTable = operations.UPDATE_TICKET_NOTIFICE(element)
    Next
    Return 0
End Function
```